# Writing custom std::set comparator for object containing array in c++

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

I am trying to make my question simple here. I have one structure with int array as member variable.

```
struct elem
{
    elem (int a, int b, int c) {id[0]=a; id[1]=b; id[2]=c;}
    int id[3];
};
```

I want to put elem pointers into std::set and I want to use find() to search specific object from that set later, so I want to provide custom comparator to this std::set.

```
struct compare
{
    bool operator() (elem *one, elem *two )
    {
            // logic 
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::set< elem *, compare> elemSet;
    std::set< elem *, compare>::iterator itr;

    elem ob1(2,5,9), ob2(5,9,7), ob3(4,3,7);

    elemSet.insert(&ob1);
    elemSet.insert(&ob2);
    elemSet.insert(&ob3);

    elem temp(4,3,7);
    itr = elemSet.find(&temp);

    if(itr != elemSet.end())
    {
        cout << endl << (*itr)->id[0] << " " << (*itr)->id[1] << " " << (*itr)->id[2]; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can you please help me with logic for comparator? Is there any generic logic for array of any size?

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Only you should know what the operator less should do for your class

Comment: Just use vector it has everything you need.

Comment: What are the semantics you want for the comparison?

Comment: @v01d - i cant use vector as number of elements can be more than 20 lakhs..

Comment: @VladimirJovic i want some logic which will satisfy strict weak ordering..

Comment: @BjörnPollex I want to compare ids like if(one->id[0] > two->id[0]) return true;...

Comment: I think if you have enough memory for array, there is no problem to use vector. I may be wrong just don't understand how the array will exist with this element count and the vector won't?

Answer (score 2):

Since `std::set` (and `std::map` and their `multi` variants) want [strict-weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), you need to provide that ordering through the comparator. Strict-weak ordering demands that

```
(x < x) == false
(x < y) == !(y < x)
((x < y) && (y < z)) == (x < z)
```

Which can be complicated to implement for classes with many members (an array is just a collection of members if you so want).

In [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218812/implementing-comparision-operators-via-tuple-and-tie-a-good-idea) I asked if it was sensible to implement strict-weak ordering through `tuple` and `tie`, which make it ridiculously easy:

```
struct compare
{
    bool operator() (elem const* one, elem const* two )
    {   // take 'tie' either from Boost or recent stdlibs
        return tie(one->id[0], one->id[1], one->id[2]) <
               tie(two->id[0], two->id[1], two->id[2]);
    }
};
```

Also notice that I take the arguments as pointers-to-`const`.