# std::set and boost::shared_ptr unique key identification issues

Tags: c++, boost, std, smart-pointers

I am having issues understanding how `std::set` (or `std::map` etc) identify unique keys. The thing I am trying to do is wrap a struct object within `boost::shared_ptr` and then store that shared pointer within `std::set` container:

Let's say the struct is a color:

```
struct Color {
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};
```

Then the container and comparison function object is defined in another class:

```
class AnotherClass {

    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Color> ColorPtr;

    public:

        struct ColorCompare {
            bool operator()(const ColorPtr &a, const ColorPtr &b) const {
                return (a->r > b->r) && (a->g > b->g) && (a->b > b->b);
            }
        };

    private:

        // Container definition
        std::set<ColorPtr, ColorCompare> colors;
};
```

The code above is failing to uniquely identify `shared_ptr` objects based on their wrapped `Color` struct. I always thought that the `std::set` container would run a comparison function on two objects, and if none of them is greater than or less than the other - it will assume they are equal. Note, that I cannot use default `shared_ptr::operator<()` and `less<...>` as that implementation is based on pointer address.

What am I missing?

p.s. I am wrapping colors within `shared_ptr` since I need to know their reference count at some point (and remove colors that are at ref count 1 - that is, only referenced by `std::set` container itself). Is there a better way to get the same result?

Comment: You could store `weak_ptr`s and remove them if they are `expired()`.

Comment: But aren't `weak_ptr`'s just observers of `shared_ptr`'s? So I still need to store or give away `shared_ptr`'s at some point. Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: `weak_ptr<T>::lock` creates a new `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison needs to be a **strict weak ordering**, which yours isn't. (For example, how are (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) ordered?) Do this:

```
return (a->r > b->r)                                   ||
       ((a->r == b->r) && (a->g > b->g))               ||
       ((a->r == b->r) && (a->g == b->g) && (a->b > b->b) );
```

This is the standard lexicographic ordering on a tuple of elements.

Note that you would write `!(b->r > a->r)` instead of `a->r == b->r` in general so that you don't introduce a dependence on a compatible equality operator, though in this simple case of floats we're fine.

By the way, you don't need a `struct`, you can simply declare a `static bool ColorCompare(...);` function. Another option is to define an `operator<` directly in the `struct Color` to make everything self-contained (so you'll just need a generic dereferencing-comparator for (smart) pointers).

Comment: The `operator<` inside `Color` won't work IIRC, as `shared_ptr` won't forward the comparision to the actual object and will simply compare the pointers. Also, this shows again just how ugly a correct implementation of strict-weak-ordering can be. [Glad I found a solution to that!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218812/implementing-comparision-operators-via-tuple-and-tie-a-good-idea)

Comment: @Xeo: You still need a generic "shared-pointer by-value comparator", but that could be done without regard to the internals of the pointee. I added a note. Good link, by the way.

Comment: That was the problem - thanks. I tried your implementation but did get some weird stl exception "invalid operator<". Then I tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/979768/454230) and that strict weak ordering algorithm seems to work great.