# Built in way to compare two (or more) values

Tags: c++, compare, operator-overloading, std

Consider implementing `operator<` for the following class:

```
struct foo {
  int a, b;
};
```

Probably the most common way is something like the element-wise lexicographic compare, like so:

```
bool operator<(foo lhs, foo rhs) {
  return lhs.a < rhs.a || (lhs.a == rhs.a && lhs.b < rhs.b);
}
```

I've written that enough times, and made a type enough times that I'm wondering if there is something built in to `std::` that will do it for me, hopefully with less boilerplate and reasonable code generation.

Now the above for two elements isn't *that* bad, but the terms multiply as you add more members.

Comment: There are some  fun tricks with `std::tie`. I'll see if I can dig up one of them.

Comment: Here's one: [operator< comparing multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312448/operator-comparing-multiple-fields)

Comment: @user4581301 - nice, looks like the [codegen is just as good](https://godbolt.org/z/YMCy50) at least for these simple cases.

Comment: And soon (C++20) [spaceship operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `pair<int, int>` instead of `struct foo`.**

As `pair<type,type>` is builtin in `std::` it has comparator for all builtin data type. So you don't need any extra operator overloading or a custom comparator. Even it works for strings. `std::` compare two `pair<type, type>` based on the first element of the pair. If it's a tie then the tie is broken based on the second element.

For example-

- `pair<int,int> a = make_pair(5,10) //declare using make_pair()`
- `pair<int,int> b = {5,7} //different way of declaring pair.`
- `pair<int,int> c = pair<int,int>(7,7) //declare using constructor`

Now `a < b == false`, `b < c == true` and `a < c == true`

So in this way, you can use `pair<type, type>` instead of struct foo. You can replace 'type' using any data type like `float, long long, char, string, pair, vector, set, map, complex` etc.