# C++ Map<>.find() overloading for different class

Tags: c++, dictionary, operator-overloading

I try to use a map which is defined as :

```
    map<Vertex,unsigned int> _addedVertices;
```

now when I use the find function to check if a vertex is already inside
I get an iterator to a wrong vertex with different information, so I have tried the following :

```
    map<Vertex,unsigned int,cmpByVertexFields> _addedVertices;
```

which didn't help.

also I have the following overloaded functions inside the Vertex class.

```
    bool operator<(const Vertex &otherV)const{
        return(_x<otherV._x && _y<otherV._y && _z<otherV._z);
    }
    bool operator==(const Vertex &otherV)const{
        return _x==otherV._x && _y==otherV._y && _z==otherV._z;
    }
```

but nothing works.
Example:
I've inserted a vertex containing (0.2,0.1,0.4)
and next thing I use is the find function with (0.2,0.15,0.41)
the iterator I get is of the first vertex instead of map.end().

What did I forget to define? 
Thanks

edit: cmpByVertexFields :

```
struct cmpByVertexFields {
    bool operator()(const Vertex& a, const Vertex& b) const {
        return a.getX()==b.getX() &&
            a.getY()==b.getY() &&
            a.getZ()==b.getZ();
    }
};
```

Comment: Your less-than `operator<` does not implement a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). This is a requirement for an `std::map` to function correctly.

Comment: I first used only x<other.x but it still didnt work.
does that not satisfy the rules too?

Comment: btw you don't need operator == at all to use map's find

Comment: I advise you to read about lexicographical ordering. Basically a struct with N fields is a bit like a string with N characters, now compare "ab" and "ba", with your operator: `"ab" < "ba"` `<=>` `'a' < 'b' and 'b' < 'a'` <=> `true and false` <=> `false`, and yet we know that "ab" IS less then "ba" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your culprit

```
bool operator<(const Vertex &otherV)const{
        return(_x<otherV._x && _y<otherV._y && _z<otherV._z);
    }
```

This doesn't yield [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering).

You need something like this

```
bool operator<(const Vertex &otherV)const{
        if(_x != otherV.x)
               return _x < otherV.x;
        if(_y != otherV.y)
               return _y < otherV.y;
        return _z < otherV.z;
    }
```

Or, equivalently and more conveniently, compare them as tuples, using std::tie

```
bool operator<(const Vertex &otherV)const{
       return std::tie(x_, y_, z_) < std::tie(OtherV.x_, OtherV.y_, OtherV.z_);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As Juan said in a comment, your `operator <` implementation is semantically incorrect. Since you’re talking about vertices, you actually need to implement a lexicographical comparison across `_x`, `_y` and `_z`.

The easiest way is to use the [`std::tuple` built-in comparison](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp):

```
bool operator<(const Vertex &otherV)const{
    return std::tie(_x, _y, _z) < std::tie(otherV._x, otherV._y, otherV._z);
}
```

[Using `std::tie` in this way](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) is now [the established way of implementing a lexicographical comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6218812/1968) across (member) variable (and you can actually use the same for the `operator==` implementation).

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys,
took me a while to understand the mistake but now I see why its not
a good comparison function.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The comparison functor or less than `operator<` must implement a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). This is a requirement for an `std::map`. Yours does not. There is no obvious and natural way to order 3D vertices, but if you want to order lexicographically by `x`, `y` and then `z` coordinate, then the easiest way is to use `std::tie` (or `boost::tie` or `std::tr1::tie` if you do not have C++11 support):

```
bool operator<(const Vertex &otherV)const{
    return std::tie(_x, _y, _z) < std::tie(otherV._x, otherV._y, otherV._z);
}
```

Note that this ordering is completely arbitrary: why would `x` take precedence over `y`? It is up to you to implement the ordering that suits the problem you are trying to solve. On the other hand, if you don't care about the actual ordering of the elements of the map, any strict weak ordering will do.