# How to implement a simple < operator

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a class with a few simple members, and would like to implement a very simple `<` operator. This is what I started with:

```
inline bool operator< (const T& lhs, const T& rhs)  { return std::tie(lhs.GetA(), lhs.GetB()) < std::tie(rhs.GetA(), rhs.GetB()); }
```

Visual studio complains with

```
Warning 2   warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'argument' : conversion from 'A' to 'A &'
```

It seems the problem is that I am not using members, but rather functions, and am passing a rvalue to a non-const ref. I guess I could save GetA() in a local A, but would rather not.

How do I fix this?

I tried adding

```
A& GetARef() const { return a; }
```

which doesn't work as I am trying to return a non-const reference with const.

```
A& GetARef() { return a; }
```

This doesn't work, as `lhs` and `rhs` are const.

Now I am thinking maybe I should use `std::tuple` or maybe `std::tie( std::cref(lhs.GetA()) )`, or maybe a new template

```
template < typename... T >
std::tuple<const T&...> ctie( const T&... args )
{
    return std::tie( args... );
}
```

But I can't help but feel that I am over complicating this...

Comment: Did you try using `std::forward_as_tuple` instead of `std::tie`?

Comment: Try `const A& GetARef() const`

Comment: Both work. Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tie` makes a tuple of *lvalue* references, and so doesn't work on temporaries (unless they are `const`, so that deduction of the tuple type gives `const` references).

You could use `make_tuple` to make a tuple of objects, or `forward_as_tuple` to get either *lvalue* or *rvalue* references depending on the arguments' value categories.

Alternatively, you could make your accessor work by returning a `const` reference to the `const` member:

```
A const & GetARef() const { return a; }
  ^^^^^
```

Comment: Standard recommendation seems to be [std::tie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218812/implementing-comparison-operators-via-tuple-and-tie-a-good-idea). Is `forward_as_tuple` always more appropriate then?

Comment: @Cookie: It's common to use `tie` with the member variables themselves, to give a nice, concise implementation. If you insist on hiding them behind accessors, then either (a) make the operator a friend, or (b) change the accessors to return (const) references, giving the caller the choice of whether to copy them, or (c) use `forward_as_tuple` to deal with the gratuitously copied objects.

Comment: I think simply fixing the getter is the way to goo.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I agree (with *goo*), returning a reference to an internal is cheap, however it means that `A` is no longer an implementation detail as it is exposed as part of the interface. A copy, while less efficient, can also become an object created from scratch, allowing more flexibility.