# How to sort a multidimensional vector of floats?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, priority-queue

So, I have a set of points in 3D, and I would like to store them in a 3 dimensional vector. Then I need sort that vector, giving priority first to the X dimention, then Y, then Z.  So, for example, if I have this set of points:

```
P1 = (5, 10 ,9)
P2 = (1, 11, 4)
P3 = (8, 5, 2)
P4 = (5, 10, 3)
P5 = (5, 4, 0)
```

I would like to get a vector sorted like this:

```
[1, 11, 4]
[5, 4, 0]
[5, 10, 3]
[5, 10, 9]
[8, 5, 2]
```

So, how can a sort a multidimentional vector taking all rows into account?
Should I use `std::priority_queue` instead? If so, how show I use it?

Thanks

Comment: You can use std::sort with a custom comparsion function.

Comment: Can you expand on that a little bit? ...So, basically, there is not a standard way to do it. I have to come out with my own function...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...giving priority first to the X dimention, then Y, then Z

Use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), something like following

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
//....

struct Points // Your 3D Point
{
    float x,y,z;
} ;

std::vector<Points> v; // Vector of 3D points

std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), 
            []( const Points& lhs, const Points& rhs )
            {
                return std::tie(lhs.x,lhs.y,lhs.z) 
                     < std::tie(rhs.x,rhs.y,rhs.z)  ; 

            }
         ) ;
```

<sub>[`DEMO`](http://rextester.com/YRR68005)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You could use an [`std::tuple<double, double, double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) to represent a point. The [comparison for `std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) works lexicographically, the way you want it to. Alternatively, you could provide a custom sort function to your vector of points. Something like this:

```
sort(pointVector.begin(), pointVector.end(), [](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs){//Implement your required comparison predicate here});
```

Also, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218812/implementing-comparison-operators-via-tuple-and-tie-a-good-idea) shows, you can achieve some sort of a named-tuple-with-lexicographic-sorting by using `std::tuple`s lexicographic sort and [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `std::sort()` to easily sort according to your specific conditions by making your own **comparator** function.

Assuming you have stored a single 3D point in a `struct point`, and the *points* in a `std::vector<points>` (A `std::tuple` might be more useful.), try out this code.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct point
{
     float x, y, z;
}
bool mySort(const point& a, const point& b)
{
    //A naive comparison to help you understand better.
    //You could always use std::tie for lexicographical comparison.
    if (a.x == b.x)
    {
        if (a.y == b.y)
            return a.z < b.z;
        else
            return a.y < b.y;
    }
    else
        return a.x < b.x;
}
int main()
{
    vector<point> graph;
    //push_back() all your points into the graph.
    //mySort() is a custom comparator function.
    sort(graph.begin(),graph.end(),mySort); 
}
```