# Function Objects Set in C++

Tags: c++

So basically I want to create a set of Function objects.
In python if we do:

```
def func():
    print "a"

a = func
b = func
fset = set()
fset.insert(a)
fset.insert(b)
```

In this case fset will have only one function since both a and b are same in python.
But in C++, if I create function objects for same function both a and b will be two different objects of a set. Is there any way that two objects of same function be same?

In C++:

```
void func(){
    cout << "a";
}

function<void()> a = bind(func);
function<void()> b = bind(func);
```

Now I want if a or its pointer is already present in the set, b should not be added.

Comment: `a` and `b` are essentially two pointers to the same object, not two instances of the same class. You can have `std::set<std::function<void()>*>`, or possibly a smart pointer - it'll behave in a similar manner.

Comment: But in this case also every time creating a pointer of
function<void()> a = function();
function<void()> b = function();
Both a and b will still have different pointers right?

Comment: A set, by definition, contains values distinct from one another.  It's not clear what you're talking about here, when you suggest that you are putting the "same function" into a set as two different objects.  Perhaps you should back up your question with some C++ code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: You say "creating a pointer", but your code doesn't actually create any pointers. It's also not clear what you mean by `function()` - that doesn't appear syntactically valid and likely won't compile.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik they are talking about _your_ comment which stores `std::function<void()>*`

Comment: Well, yes - but *their* code doesn't manipulate pointers, so it's not clear what they plan to put into that set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs using pre- and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::set has duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119602/stdset-has-duplicate-entry)

Comment: @paddy I have added some C++ code to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only void functions(or all functions have the same signature), use simply C type function pointers as `std::sets`'s template type.

This will work and as a plus no type erasure overheads of `std::function`.

```
void func() {}
void func2() {}

using fPtrType = void(*)(); // convenience type  

int main()
{
    std::set<fPtrType> fset;
    fPtrType a = func;
    fPtrType b = func;
    fset.emplace(a);
    fset.emplace(b);
    fset.emplace(func2);

    std::cout << fset.size();  // prints 2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will this also work if both a and b have a different scope?

Comment: @250 Did you mean [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VjwgC8Fai4dsLqHr).