# Compare tuples of different sizes

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

Why isn't it possible to compare two tuples of different size like this:

```
#include <tuple>
int main() {
  std::tuple<int, int> t1(1, 2);
  std::tuple<int> t2(1);
  if(std::tuple_size<decltype(t1)>::value == std::tuple_size<decltype(t2)>::value)
    return (t1 == t2);
  else
    return 0;
}
```

I know that `t1==t2` is not possible. But in this example it wouldn't be executed. Is there a possibility to compare tuples of different sizes?

Comment: The question isn't why it is not possible; the question is why do you want to do so?

Comment: Do you mean checking if one tuple begins with another?

Comment: my question would be: what do you mean with "it isnt possible", what is the error messages. Sorry, I am just too lazy to copy it and find out myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator==` requires the tuples to be of equal lengths.

§ 20.4.2.7 [tuple.rel]:

> ```
> template<class... TTypes, class... UTypes>
> constexpr bool operator==(const tuple<TTypes...>& t, const tuple<UTypes...>& u);
> ```
>
> <sup>1</sup> *Requires*: For all `i`, where `0 <= i` and `i < sizeof...(TTypes)`, `get<i>(t) == get<i>(u)` is a valid expression returning a type that is convertible to `bool`. `sizeof...(TTypes) == sizeof...(UTypes)`.

If you want two tuples of different lengths to be considered *unequal*, you'd need to implement this logic yourself:

```
template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
auto compare(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t1, const std::tuple<Us...>& t2)
    -> typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Ts) == sizeof...(Us), bool>::type
{
    return t1 == t2;
}

template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
auto compare(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t1, const std::tuple<Us...>& t2)
    -> typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Ts) != sizeof...(Us), bool>::type
{
    return false;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df99e90111a7f17a)

This way, the code comparing two tuples, `t1 == t2`, is instantiated only when the lengths of tuples match each other. In your scenario, a compiler is unable to compile your code, since there is no predefined `operator==` for such a case.

Answer (score 1):

You may write several overloads:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
bool is_equal(const std::tuple<Ts...>& lhs, const std::tuple<Ts...>& rhs)
{
    return lhs == rhs;
}

template<typename ...Ts, typename... Us>
bool is_equal(const std::tuple<Ts...>&, const std::tuple<Us...>&)
{
    return false;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/WCiGSq)

Answer (score -1):

You have problem with size mismatch. Read this, maybe it can help you.
[Implementing comparison operators via 'tuple' and 'tie', a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218812/implementing-comparison-operators-via-tuple-and-tie-a-good-idea)

Comment: I've edited your answer to make the link functional, though this would IMHO be better posted as a comment rather than an answer, since it's essentially a link-only response.