# How to compare assembly code

Tags: c++, assembly

**EDIT:** Changed MWE to avoid to much optimization which reduced the handwritten version to `1`.

So after reading this discussion here: [Implementing comparison operators via 'tuple' and 'tie', a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218812/implementing-comparison-operators-via-tuple-and-tie-a-good-idea), I wanted to check one of the statements that was made in the comments (JohannesD):

> Was positively surprised to see that the compiler inlined and optimized out everything having to do with tuples and references, emitting assembly almost identical to hand-written code.

**Question 1:** How to properly check this statement?

So here is what I tried: Since I never before touched or looked at assembly I wanted to have the most simple code example possible. However, I also want to compare the assembly versions optimized by the compiler to not get clutter from not-inlined functions etc. The result was that the compiler basically optimized my entire MWE away. Therefore, I added the `cout`. But this of course introduces some unwanted clutter to the assembly.

**Question 2:** What are neat tricks to avoid the code from being optimized away completely without introducing to much new code?

So my MWE at the moment is the one you find below. Using Visual Studio in release mode I compiled the code and used this to see the assembly: [How to view the assembly behind the code using Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020498/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-using-visual-c). First I made sure that the C++14 suggestion (the `auto tied()...` line) yields the exact same assembly code as the one without this extra function, which it does. Then I wanted to compare it to the handwritten code but get completely different assembly output, or so it seems since I don't really know much about assembly.

**Question 3:** I see similar lines between the two versions but lots of additional lines in the one that uses tuple. What do these additional lines do?

**Question 4:** Length of assembly does not equal slowness of code. Ok, but how much can one actually read out of this assemblies about performance of the two versions?

**MWE - EDIT: Now without getting optimized away hopefully**

```
    #include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct item_new {
    item_new(int lx = 0, int ly = 0, int lz = 0, int ld = 0) :x(lx), y(ly), z(lz), d(ld) {}
    int x, y, z, d;
    auto tied() const { return std::tie(z, y, x, d); }
    bool operator<(const item_new &rhs) const {
        return tied() < rhs.tied();
    }
};

struct item {
    item(int lx = 0, int ly = 0, int lz = 0, int ld = 0) :x(lx), y(ly), z(lz), d(ld) {}
    int x, y, z, d;
    bool operator<(const item &rhs) const {
        if (z < rhs.z)
            return true;
        if (z == rhs.z) {
            if (y < rhs.y)
                return true;
            if (y == rhs.y) {
                if (x < rhs.x)
                    return true;
                if (x == rhs.x && d < rhs.d)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};


int main()
{
    int x,y,z,d;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cin >> z;
    std::cin >> d;
    item a(x, y, z, d), b(7, 8, 9, 0);
    //item_new a(x,y,z,d), b(7,8,9,0);
    bool result = a<b;

    std::cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

**Assembly of handwritten version**

```
    int main()
{
012B1002  in          al,dx  
012B1003  and         esp,0FFFFFFF8h  
012B1006  sub         esp,18h  
012B1009  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[012B3004h]  
012B100E  xor         eax,esp  
012B1010  mov         dword ptr [esp+14h],eax  
    int x,y,z,d;
    std::cin >> x;
012B1014  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[12B2038h]  
012B101A  lea         eax,[esp+0Ch]  
012B101E  push        eax  
012B101F  call        dword ptr ds:[12B2034h]  
    std::cin >> y;
012B1025  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[12B2038h]  
012B102B  lea         eax,[esp+8]  
012B102F  push        eax  
012B1030  call        dword ptr ds:[12B2034h]  
    std::cin >> z;
012B1036  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[12B2038h]  
012B103C  lea         eax,[esp+4]  
012B1040  push        eax  
012B1041  call        dword ptr ds:[12B2034h]  
    std::cin >> d;
012B1047  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[12B2038h]  
    std::cin >> d;
012B104D  lea         eax,[esp+10h]  
012B1051  push        eax  
012B1052  call        dword ptr ds:[12B2034h]  
    item a(x, y, z, d), b(7, 8, 9, 0);
    //item_new a(x,y,z,d), b(7,8,9,0);
    bool result = a<b;
012B1058  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+4]  
012B105C  cmp         eax,9  
012B105F  jge         main+67h (012B1067h)  
012B1061  mov         byte ptr [esp],1  
012B1065  jmp         main+8Eh (012B108Eh)  
012B1067  jne         main+8Ah (012B108Ah)  
012B1069  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+8]  
012B106D  cmp         eax,8  
012B1070  jl          main+61h (012B1061h)  
012B1072  jne         main+8Ah (012B108Ah)  
012B1074  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+0Ch]  
012B1078  cmp         eax,7  
012B107B  jl          main+61h (012B1061h)  
012B107D  jne         main+8Ah (012B108Ah)  
012B107F  cmp         dword ptr [esp+10h],0  
012B1084  mov         byte ptr [esp],1  
012B1088  jl          main+8Eh (012B108Eh)  
012B108A  mov         byte ptr [esp],0  

    std::cout << result;
012B108E  push        dword ptr [esp]  
012B1091  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[12B2040h]  
012B1097  call        dword ptr ds:[12B203Ch]  
    return 0;
}
012B109D  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+14h]  
012B10A1  xor         eax,eax  
012B10A3  xor         ecx,esp  
012B10A5  call        __security_check_cookie (012B10AEh)  
012B10AA  mov         esp,ebp  
012B10AC  pop         ebp  
012B10AD  ret
```

**Assembly of version using std::tie**

```
    int main()
{
00F41002  in          al,dx  
00F41003  and         esp,0FFFFFFF8h  
00F41006  sub         esp,3Ch  
00F41009  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[00F43004h]  
00F4100E  xor         eax,esp  
00F41010  mov         dword ptr [esp+38h],eax  
    int x,y,z,d;
    std::cin >> x;
00F41014  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[0F42038h]  
00F4101A  lea         eax,[esp+8]  
00F4101E  push        esi  
00F4101F  push        eax  
00F41020  call        dword ptr ds:[0F42034h]  
    std::cin >> y;
00F41026  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[0F42038h]  
00F4102C  lea         eax,[esp+10h]  
00F41030  push        eax  
00F41031  call        dword ptr ds:[0F42034h]  
    std::cin >> z;
00F41037  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[0F42038h]  
00F4103D  lea         eax,[esp+14h]  
00F41041  push        eax  
00F41042  call        dword ptr ds:[0F42034h]  
    std::cin >> d;
00F41048  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[0F42038h]  
00F4104E  lea         eax,[esp+18h]  
00F41052  push        eax  
00F41053  call        dword ptr ds:[0F42034h]  
    //item a(x, y, z, d), b(7, 8, 9, 0);
    item_new a(x,y,z,d), b(7,8,9,0);
00F41059  mov         edx,dword ptr [esp+14h]  
00F4105D  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr ds:[0F42110h]  
00F41064  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+0Ch]  
00F41068  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+10h]  
00F4106C  mov         esi,dword ptr [esp+18h]  
00F41070  mov         dword ptr [esp+1Ch],eax  
00F41074  mov         dword ptr [esp+20h],ecx  
00F41078  mov         dword ptr [esp+24h],edx  
00F4107C  mov         dword ptr [esp+28h],esi  
00F41080  movups      xmmword ptr [esp+2Ch],xmm0  
    bool result = a<b;
00F41085  cmp         edx,9  
00F41088  jl          main+0A5h (0F410A5h)  
00F4108A  jg          main+9Eh (0F4109Eh)  
00F4108C  cmp         ecx,8  
00F4108F  jl          main+0A5h (0F410A5h)  
00F41091  jg          main+9Eh (0F4109Eh)  
00F41093  cmp         eax,7  
00F41096  jl          main+0A5h (0F410A5h)  
00F41098  jg          main+9Eh (0F4109Eh)  
00F4109A  test        esi,esi  
00F4109C  js          main+0A5h (0F410A5h)  
00F4109E  mov         byte ptr [esp+8],0  
00F410A3  jmp         main+0AAh (0F410AAh)  
00F410A5  mov         byte ptr [esp+8],1  

    std::cout << result;
00F410AA  push        dword ptr [esp+8]  
00F410AE  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[0F42040h]  
00F410B4  call        dword ptr ds:[0F4203Ch]  
    return 0;
}
00F410BA  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+3Ch]  
00F410BE  xor         eax,eax  
00F410C0  pop         esi  
00F410C1  xor         ecx,esp  
00F410C3  call        __security_check_cookie (0F410CCh)  
00F410C8  mov         esp,ebp  
00F410CA  pop         ebp  
00F410CB  ret
```

Comment: I recommend storing the assembly languages in two separate files.  Next open them side by side in an editor (or open in different editor instances and place side by side).  I find this an easy method for comparing assembly languages.  Another tip is to use a file comparison utility with the two assembly language files.

Comment: First, I think your assembly dumps are incorrect, how did you create them?  Your first instruction is "in al,dx", which is not going to appear in the code you use, and it is also aligned at xxxxxx02, which is not valid alignment to begin a function on anything since about 1985.  Second, your hand-written example reduced down to a constant "1" even with the cout, so cout didn't help.

Comment: I assume you are really just interested in the speed of the code between the two versions? Why not just measure that?

Comment: Write functions that take args and return a value, so they can't optimize away.  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34410357/224132.  Static analysis of asm performance is *hard*.  Microbenchmarks with perf counters are often helpful.  See the perf guides in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), esp. [Agner Fog's microarch guide](http://agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: What are the conditions for the function to not be optimized away, because I have tried now several things, but the debugger always tells me that the line of code I want to set a breakpoint to is not part of the current assembly.

Comment: @MattJordan See my updated MWE which now does not reduce to 1. However, the in al,dx still appears.

Comment: Does [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4976862e7f430cbd) help?

Comment: Since you are using Visual Studio, why not just enable assembly code output in the configuration settings for your project (or on command-line with /FAscu).  That will get you the assembler output without the hassle of a debugger.

Comment: @nwp I see, the output is quite similar, but I don't know what to make of the differences.