# Implementing the '<' operator

Tags: c++, dictionary, operator-keyword

What is the correct way to implement the '<' operator for using the following simple class as a key in a `std::map` (functions are omitted)?

```
class Person
{
public:
   bool valid = false;
   std::string name = "";
   std::string id = "";
}
```

Comment: not a dupe but a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: You havea field named `id`. Its name implies that it is unique. Is it? If so, you could make use of that fact.

Comment: There is no "the correct" way. It is up to you really, as long as it satisfies *strict weak ordering*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

```
class Person
{
public:
    bool valid = false;
    std::string name = "";
    std::string id = "";

    bool operator<(const Person& r) const
    {
        return std::tie(valid, name, id) < std::tie(r.valid, r.name, r.id);
    }
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

`std::tie(xs...)` creates an [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) of references to the passed `xs...` arguments. [Comparison between two `std::tuple` instances](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) works by *lexicographically* comparing the elements, thus providing an ordering for your type.

More information [here on cppsamples](http://www.cppsamples.com/common-tasks/lexicographic-ordering.html) and [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218812/implementing-comparison-operators-via-tuple-and-tie-a-good-idea).

Comment: @RichardHodges: now let's fight for **member function** vs **free function**!

Comment: Better yet explain how/why `tie` is the way to go/what it is doing.

Comment: always free functions for binary ops :)

Comment: @NathanOliver: added a brief explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::tie` as suggested by the other answers. If you want to clearly see the logic in your own function or don't have access to a C++11 compiler, you can implement it as:

```
class Person
{
   public:
      bool valid = false;
      std::string name = "";
      std::string id = "";

      bool operator<(Person const& rhs) const
      {
         if ( this->valid != rhs.valid )
         {
            return ( this->valid < rhs.valid );
         }
         if ( this->name != rhs.name )
         {
            return ( this->name < rhs.name );
         }
         return ( this->id < rhs.id );
      }
};
```

Comment: If it were me, I'd make it so all invalid objects are equivalent without relying on the other members. That's something you can't do with `std::tie`.

Comment: It should be noted, that `std::tuple` uses equivalency, while this implementation uses equality. It's the same for these types, but not in general.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

class Person
{
public:
   bool valid = false;
   std::string name = "";
   std::string id = "";
};

bool operator<(const Person& l, const Person& r)
{
    return std::tie(l.valid, l.name, l.id) < std::tie(r.valid, r.name, r.id);
}
```